# Supremum characterisation of entropy

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convex-analysis, concentration-of-measure

Why is it true that for 
$ g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+} $
and any measure $\mu$
$$ \int_{}^{}g \cdot \log(g) d\mu - \int_{}^{}g d\mu \cdot \log(\int_{}^{}g d\mu) = sup_{f: \int_{}^{}e^{f}d\mu \le 1}\int_{}^{}f \cdot g d\mu$$

Any references, hints greatly welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective function is concave and the constraint defines a convex set, so we can use Lagrange's method.

Let 
$$
L\triangleq \int fgd\mu+\lambda\left(1-\int e^fd\mu\right).
$$
Let further $e^f=:h$, or $f=\log h$. Then
$$
L=\int (\log h)gd\mu+\lambda\left(1-\int hd\mu\right).
$$
Suppose $h$ is optimal, and consider perturbing it infinitesimally by $\delta h$. Then
$$
\delta L= \int \frac{1}{h}\delta hgd\mu-\lambda\int \delta hd\mu
= \int\left(\frac{g}{h}-\lambda\right)\delta hd\mu.
$$
The optimality assumption requires $\frac{g}{h}\equiv\lambda$, or $h=\lambda^{-1}g$. Since $g$ is positive, the constraint must be binding, so $\int hd\mu=1$, or $\lambda=\int gd\mu$. Finally,
\begin{align}
\sup\int fgd\mu
& =\int(\log(\lambda^{-1}g))gd\mu\\
& = \int(\log g)gd\mu-\log\left(\int gd\mu\right)\int gd\mu.
\end{align}

Comment: Is there an accessible reference of this result?